# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (old android application)

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I imported an Android app built with Eclipse to Android Studio. As I try to run this application using emulator, following error occurs.

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:98)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:24)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:207)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:133)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:125)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
... 32 more
```

I cannot seem to find the cause of the problem. I have tried every single posts I can google, but no luck unfortunately. Any hint??

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
//TODO: Line 7 added as SDK version changed from 26 to 22
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "wvi.app.hannam"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 26
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalytics.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="wvi.app.hannam"
android:versionCode="11"
android:versionName="1.5.6" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>


<!-- For Donut and above we must specify that we use the camera, but intentionally omit the
autofocus feature in order for the app to appear in Market for non-AF devices. While it's true
that 1D barcodes will not be scannable, QR Codes will work. Ideally we'd show users a message
to this effect on first launch. -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Add: start -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- Add: end -->

<uses-permission android:name="wvi.app.hannam.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<permission
    android:name="wvi.app.hannam.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">


    <!-- Add: start -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!-- Add: end -->

    <!--
    <receiver
        android:name=".pushEvent.push_receiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="wvi.app.hannam" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="wvi.app.hannam" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    -->

    <!-- Add: start 2015-11-06 -->
    <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="wvi.app.hannam" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

    <!-- [START gcm_listener_service] -->
    <service
        android:name="wvi.app.hannam.pushEvent.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener_service] -->

    <!-- [START instanceId_listener_service] -->
    <service
        android:name="wvi.app.hannam.pushEvent.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener_service] -->

    <!-- [START gcm_registration_service] -->
    <service
        android:name="wvi.app.hannam.pushEvent.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_registration_service] -->
    <!-- Add: end 2015-11-06 -->

    <activity
        android:name=".zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="wvi.app.hannam.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Allow web apps to launch Barcode Scanner by linking to http://zxing.appspot.com/scan. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="zxing.appspot.com"
                android:path="/scan"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- We also support a Google Product Search URL. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.google.com"
                android:path="/m/products/scan"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- And the UK version. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.google.co.uk"
                android:path="/m/products/scan"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".zxing.client.android.PreferencesActivity"
        android:label="@string/preferences_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity"
        android:label="@string/share_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="wvi.app.hannam.zxing.client.android.ENCODE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- This allows us to handle the Share button in Contacts. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- This allows us to handle sharing any plain text . -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".zxing.client.android.book.SearchBookContentsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/sbc_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="wvi.app.hannam.zxing.client.android.SEARCH_BOOK_CONTENTS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".zxing.client.android.wifi.WifiActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/wa_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".zxing.client.android.share.ShareActivity"
        android:label="@string/share_name"
        android:screenOrientation="user"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="wvi.app.hannam.zxing.client.android.SHARE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".zxing.client.android.share.BookmarkPickerActivity"
        android:label="@string/bookmark_picker_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".zxing.client.android.share.AppPickerActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_picker_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".zxing.client.android.HelpActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="user" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".zxing.client.android.Web"
        android:screenOrientation="user" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".transaction.transaction_history" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".setting.setting_main" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".main_intro" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".main_menu" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".flyer.flyer_main" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".giftCard.gift_main" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".info.info_main" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".memCard.member_main" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".product.product_main" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".product.product_search_result" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".pushEvent.push_event_main" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".pushEvent.push_event_popup" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".qna.qna_main" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".qna.qna_view" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".qna.qna_write" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".login.login_agree"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login_agree" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".login.login_process"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login_process" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="main_unconnected" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".setting.setting_esteregg"></activity>
</application>

<!-- Wifi related  -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

---

Unfortunately, Stack Overflow only allows up to 30k characters. 
Here is the result from `.\gradlew wrapper --info --debug --stacktrace`:
[result](https://snipsave.com/rayroh/#/snippet/J3IaaL321urprdcwLQ)

Comment: Firstly, change `compile` to `implementation` because you are using the Android Gradle Plugin 3.0+ tools, Secondly, from command line, run `./gradlew assemble --info --debug --stacktrace` to get more helpful logs about your errors. And then update your question so that others can help further.

Comment: @shizhen thank you for your tip. I will do so shortly

Comment: @shizhen Ive just added the result of gradlew :)

Comment: It looks like a connection issue, are you working behind a proxy?

Comment: @shizhen I am not working behind a proxy.. hmm.. Do you think it is possible t o be caused by outdated SDK API level?

Comment: It looks lore like a grade version issue, can you try clean your grade caches?

Comment: Just noticed that the command you run was not `./gradlew assemble --info --debug --stacktrace`. running assemble will compile your project but `wrapper` won't